# Export EML from Email using MailKit

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, imap, mailkit, mimekit

I need to export an EML file from IMAP using Mailkit, however there are no methods to export the emails.

I didn't find any documentation either in [MimeKit - Mailkit Documentation](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Introduction.htm).

Is it possible to export EML files using Mailkit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are looking for is [MimeMessage.WriteTo()](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MimeKit_MimeMessage_WriteTo.htm)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write `MailMessage` to `.eml` file using **MimeKit**, use this code

```
var mimeMessage = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mail);
mimeMessage.WriteTo(new FileStream(@"path_to_file\new_mail.eml", FileMode.Create));
```